# What is the Rust equivalent to append in Go?

Tags: go, rust

I am trying to figure out on my own reading through documentation, but with no luck on how to convert this Go function into Rust:

```
func main() {
  cards := []string{"Ace of Diamonds", newCard()}
  cards = append(cards, "Six of Spades")

  fmt.Println(cards)
}

func newCard() string {
  return "Five of Diamonds"
}
```

This is not correct, at least the cards.append I know is wrong:

```
fn main() {
    let mut cards: [&str; 2] = ["Ace of Diamonds", new_card()];
    let mut additional_card: [&str; 1] = ["Six of Spades"];
    cards.append(additional_card);

    println!("cards")
}

fn new_card() -> &'static str  {
    "Five of Diamonds"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. like in Go, Rust arrays are fixed size.

The type `[&str; 2]` in Rust is roughly equivalent to `[2]string` in Go, which you also can't `append` to.

The closest to a Go slice you can get to in Rust is a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html) which you can use like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut cards = vec!["Ace of Diamonds", new_card()];
    let additional_cards: [&str; 2] = ["Six of Spades", "Seven of Clubs"];
    // for anything that implements `IntoIterator` of cards
    cards.extend(additional_cards);
    // or for a single card only
    cards.push("Three of Hearts");

    println!("{cards:?}")
}

fn new_card() -> &'static str {
    "Five of Diamonds"
}
```

Comment: okay so you have to `extend()` in Rust. But in Go, at least the version I have worked on you can do `append()`. Anyways, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Daniel Note that if you're pushing one element `.push()` is better.